# PHP echo multiple array foreach

Tags: php, arrays

Somehow I could not print areas with PHP array loop

How should I write code to print all areas of the array

Please Help
Thank you ,

Sample Array

```
Array ( [ackCode] => success
   [responseTime] => 10/12/2015 18:33:36
   [timeElapsed] => 108 ms
   [saleCount] => 6
    [sales] => Array (
         [sale] => Array (
              [0] => Array (
              [saleCode] => SC23423423
              [productId] => 196785348                
              [price] => 14.70
              [buyerInfo] => Array (
                     [username] => Debene
                     [name] => adi
                     [surname] => soyadi
              [1] => Array (
              [saleCode] => SC154565
              [productId] => 196208512
              [price] => 24.9
              [buyerInfo] => Array (
                     [[username] => Debene2
                     [name] => adi2
                     [surname] => soyadi2
                     [variantId] => 38351116
                     [variantSpecs] => Array (
                             [variantSpec] => Array (
                                     [0] => Array (
                                      [name] => Renk
                                      [value] => Gri
                                      [stockCode] =>
                                     )
                                     [1] => Array (
                                     [name] => Beden
                                     [value] => M
                                     [stockCode] => )
              ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What error or unexpected results did you get?  You need to provide more info.  Have you tried any of these functions:  `print_r($myArray)`, `var_dump($myArray)`, or `var_export($myArray)`.

Comment: I want to print array areas for example `echo $array["surname"];`

Comment: For the array given above: `echo $myArray['sales']['sale'][0]['buyerInfo']['surname'];`

Comment: Thank you **BareNakedCoder**

Comment: foeach($myArray['sales']['sale'][0]['buyerInfo'] as $res) { 
echo $res['username']; } 
and so on for buyerinfo array